# Spring Integration - aggregate and transform

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

What would be the simplest integration component arrangement in my use case:

1. Receive messages from multiple sources and in multiple formats (all messages are JSON serialized objects).
2. Store messages in buffer up to 10 seconds (aggregate)
3. Group messages by different class property getter (eg class1.someId(), class2.otherId(), ...)
4. Release all messages that are grouped and transform to new aggregated message.

So far (point 1. and 2.), I'm using aggregator, but don't know if there is out of box solution for problem at 3.) - or I will have to try to cast each Message and check if type of object is class1 - then use correlationstrategy someId, if class2 then otherId.

For problem 4.) - I could manually code something - but Transformer seems like a good component to use, I just don't know if there is something like aggregating transformer where I can specify mapping rules for each input type.

**UPDATE**

Something like this:

```
class One{
    public String getA(){ return "1"; }
}

class Two{
    public Integer getB(){ return 1; }
}

class ReduceTo{
    public void setId(Integer id){}
    public void setOne(One one){}
    public void setTwo(Two two){}
}

public class ReducingAggregator {


    @CorrelationStrategyMethod
    public String strategy(One one){
        return one.getA();
    }

    @CorrelationStrategyMethod
    public String strategy(Two two){
        return two.getB().toString();
    }

    @AggregatorMethod
    public void reduce(ReduceTo out, One in){
        out.setId(Integer.valueOf(in.getA()));
        out.setOne(in);
    }

    @AggregatorMethod
    public void reduce(ReduceTo out, Two in){
        out.setId(in.getB());
        out.setTwo(in);
    }
}
```

Annotations have, I suppose, different use-case than current spring ones. RediceTo could be any object including collections. In config we could specify when passed first time should it be empty list or something else (like reduce in java streams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you would like to see as out-of-the-box solution. That is your classes, so your methods. How Framework may make some decision on them?

Well, yes, you need to implement `CorrelationStrategy`. Or you can consider to use `ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy` and don't write the Java code :-).

Please, elaborate more what you would like to see as an out-of-the-box feature.

The `aggregating transformer` is encapsulated exactly in the `MessageGroupProcessor` function of the Aggregator. By default it is `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor`. Yes, you can code your own or again - use an `ExpressionEvaluatingMessageGroupProcessor` and don't write Java code again :-)

Comment: No, there is nothing on the matter in the Framework. You should stick with what I suggested for you - custom `CorrelationStrategy` and custom `MesaageGroupProcessor`. I would even suggest to send different objects to different aggregators with the functions specific to that type. `MethodInvokingCorrelationStrategy` may select the target method to call by the payload type though.

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll probably use MethodInvokingCorrelationStrategy, and custom implement MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor if does not already exists.

Comment: The aggregator is very complex component already. To add some smart logic based on new set of annotations would over complicate it more. More over people are looking more and more to the functional programming, where one of the advantages is a simple way to avoid annotation restrictions. So Java DSL is there for you